# Two elements positioning one over another

Tags: html, css

[image: Desired result]

```css
.holderDiv{
 position: relative;
}
.shadowSimulation{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: black;
 height: 60%;
 width: 611px;
 bottom: -10px;
 left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="holderDiv">
  <img class="confidentalMainImage" src="http://i.imgur.com/SoHn5gF.jpg">
  <div class="shadowSimulation"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have attached an image of what I need to get.
In the code sample, I have tried with `z-index` but still not a result.
I need to get the black part back to the image. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

I found answer myself, the solution was to give `position: relative` to an image and higher `z-index:` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add a shadow directly to the image or the div that contains it?

It maybe a better solution because of problems with different web browsers.

Here is a **[codepen](https://codepen.io/estemon/pen/wqEQzE)** with a modified example, and code below, hope it helps

css:

```
.holderDiv {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 611px;
    box-shadow: -20px 20px 0 Gray;
}
```